# Combine multiple rows into single row in an CSV file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I load data from SQL to CSV file. And my csv records are in the following way.

```
Eid  ename  desig  sourceD  location  
1     Ralf   PM      1        UK  
1     Ralf   PM      1        USA  
2     Marty  PL      3         GBR  
3     Levis  BA      5        UK  
4     Ricky  BI      7        RSA  
4     Ricky  BI      7        FRA
```

now i want to combine EID 1 and 4 into single rows. My output has to be in the following way

```
Eid  ename  desig  sourceD  location  
1     Ralf   PM      1        UK, USA  
2     Marty  PL      3         GBR  
3     Levis  BA      5        UK  
4     Ricky  BI      7        RSA, FRA
```

I have only CSV File i dont have any sql Query or anything.

Comment: You are lodaing this data from table?

Comment: yes am loading the data using sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df362/7)

SQL Query

```
    select c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD,
    (   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) as Locations
from Contacts c1
group by c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD
```

Working ?

If you want without comma in the end:

```
    SELECT c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD,
   LEFT( (   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),LEN((   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ))-1) AS Locations
FROM Contacts c1
GROUP BY c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD
```

This Query will let you avoid lenght 0:

```
    SELECT c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD,
   LEFT( (   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),CASE WHEN LEN((   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ))=0 THEN 1 ELSE LEN((   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    )) END -1) AS Locations
FROM Contacts c1
GROUP BY c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD
```

Comment: HI, i have almost 150 cloumns, when i ran after making changes, it is saying invalid length parameter passed to the substring.

Comment: the error give you second query LEN() function. Need somehow to delete last comma without using LEN() function. OR you have People who don't have location... The lenght somehow is equal 1 or 0 so this error alert.

Comment: You need to find these records where LEN() = 0:<br/>
`select c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD,
    (   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) as Locations
from Contacts c1
WHERE 
LEN((   SELECT x.location + ', '
        FROM Contacts x
        WHERE c1.Eid = x.Eid
        ORDER BY x.location
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ))=0
group by c1.Eid, c1.ename,c1.desig,c1.sourceD`<br/>
And correct them or you can put 0 if lenght is 0 I updated my answer.